# No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation

Tags: java, spring, repository, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I'm trying to extend the **SimpleJpaRepository ** by BaseRepository interface and the BaseRepositoryImpl.
Tha BaseRepositoryImpl extends **SimpleJpaRepository ** and implements BaseRepository.

In addition, I have some other Repositories such as CandidateRepository and EmployeeRepository that extends the BaseRepository.

Below you can see the code following the error:

[To see the project structure click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HigXG.jpg)

```
    @NoRepositoryBean  
    public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID>{
//..
}


@Repository
public abstract class BaseRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends 
                                                    SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseRepository<T, ID>{

    private final EntityManager em;

    public BaseRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T,ID> entityInformation, 
                                EntityManager entityManager) {

      super(entityInformation, entityManager);
      this.em = entityManager;

  }
  //..
}
```

The extend Repositories:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
    public interface CandidateRepository extends BaseRepository<DatCandidate, UUID>{

        //..
    }


@Repository(value="CandidateRepositoryImpl")
public class CandidateRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepositoryImpl<DatCandidate, UUID> implements CandidateRepository{


    public CandidateRepositoryImpl(
            JpaEntityInformation<DatCandidate, UUID> entityInformation,
            EntityManager entityManager) {

        super(entityInformation, entityManager);

    }
}
```

Here is my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.projects"></context:component-scan>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.projects.repositories.impl" 
    base-class="com.projects.repositories.impl.BaseRepositoryImpl"></jpa:repositories>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="punit" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
                <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none"/>
                <entry key="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/relocationdb?autoReconnect=true" />
        <property name="username" value="root"></property>
        <property name="password" value="1234" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

Service:

```
@Service(value="CandidateServiceImpl")
public class CandidateServiceImpl extends BaseServiceImpl<CandidateForCreationDto, CandidateDto,DatCandidate, UUID> 
                                implements CandidateService{

    private CandidateRepositoryImpl  candidateRepository;

        @Autowired
    public CandidateServiceImpl (
            @Qualifier("CandidateRepositoryImpl") JpaRepository<DatCandidate, UUID> candidateRepository
            ) {
        this.candidateRepository = (CandidateRepositoryImpl)candidateRepository;
    }
}
```

The Error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

I followed the Spring JPA documentation, but can't understand the error

attached is the running code

> 4:39:10 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate
>   Core {5.2.12.Final} March 21, 2018 4:39:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  INFO: HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found March 21, 2018 4:39:10 PM
>   org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager
>    INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations
>   {5.0.1.Final} March 21, 2018 4:39:12 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect
>    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect March 21, 2018 4:39:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart SEVERE:
>   Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of
>   class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'candidateController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'candidateBaseService'; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'CandidateServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\alon\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Relocation\WEB-INF\classes\com\projects\service\impl\CandidateServiceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'CandidateRepositoryImpl' defined in
>   file
>   [C:\Users\alon\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Relocation\WEB-INF\classes\com\projects\repositories\impl\CandidateRepositoryImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5110)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5633)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1700)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1690)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'CandidateServiceImpl' defined in file
>   [C:\Users\alon\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Relocation\WEB-INF\classes\com\projects\service\impl\CandidateServiceImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'CandidateRepositoryImpl' defined in
>   file
>   [C:\Users\alon\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Relocation\WEB-INF\classes\com\projects\repositories\impl\CandidateRepositoryImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
>     ... 24 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'CandidateRepositoryImpl' defined in
>   file
>   [C:\Users\alon\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Relocation\WEB-INF\classes\com\projects\repositories\impl\CandidateRepositoryImpl.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
>     ... 37 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformation' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies
>   as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721)
>     ... 51 more
>
> מרץ 21, 2018 4:39:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext
>   startInternal SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full
>   details will be found in the appropriate container log file מרץ 21,
>   2018 4:39:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: Context [/Relocation] startup failed due to previous errors
>   מרץ 21, 2018 4:39:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext
>   log INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext מרץ 21, 2018
>   4:39:16 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
>   clearReferencesJdbc SEVERE: The web application [/Relocation]
>   registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] but failed to
>   unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a
>   memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered. מרץ 21,
>   2018 4:39:16 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
>   clearReferencesThreads SEVERE: The web application [/Relocation]
>   appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup
>   thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a
>   memory leak. מרץ 21, 2018 4:39:16 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] מרץ 21, 2018 4:39:16 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] מרץ 21, 2018 4:39:16 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   17422 ms

Comment: The exception is very straight-forward: spring cannot find a implementation for JpaEntityInformation. Just need to found out "why". Can you share a running code example so I can easily reproduce the problem?

Comment: The running code was attached to the question

Comment: please format stacktraces as code not as quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You are doing a somewhat weird combination of things here.

On the one hand, you effectively disable all the Spring Data stuff by using `@NoRepositoryBean` on  `CandidateRepository` and providing your own implementation. But then your implementation is based extends `SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>` which is a core component of Spring Data but it doesn't get configured properly since you basically disabled it.

I guess it's time to make up your mind:

1. Do you want to change the behavior that is provided by `SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>`? Possibly adding methods to your base implementation.

   If so extend it, leaving constructors as they are and use it as your [`repositoryBaseClass`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#repositoryBaseClass--). [Here is a tutorial how to do that](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-adding-custom-methods-into-all-repositories/).
2. Just provide custom implementation for one (or some) repositories. Then use [custom implementations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior).

Answer (score 2):

Being pragmatic, you're trying to extend `SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID>`, but once you disabling it Spring does not load any implementation of `JpaEntityInformation` and thus the exception.

Also, as @jens-schauder said, your mixing concepts.

Try to follow this [very well explained tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-method-in-all-repositories) to see if it helps.